# Why my image is not displayed?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class "nuhoLogo">

    <a class "nuhoLogo" href="http://www.nuho.com">
```

//should't this path always work?

```
    <img src="C:/Users/Chibas/Desktop/html/MyWebSite/Logo/logo.gif" border="0" width="100" height="80" alt ="nuho-logo"/>

    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: If that is the correct path.

Comment: Because ```src="C:/Users/Chibas/Desktop/html/MyWebSite/Logo/logo.gif"```

Comment: You have the CSS div # info in the alt tag. Is your folder here? 'C:/Users/Chibas/Desktop/html/MyWebSite/Logo/logo.gif'

Comment: @mlegg sorry i can't understand what exactly you want to say

Comment: Do you have nothing in your page ot the word nuho-logo ?
Are you sure your path to the image : "C:/Users/Chibas/Desktop/html/MyWebSite/Logo/logo.gif" is good ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized what was wrong i liked my image as : 
src="Logo/nuhologo.gif"

and for some reason it worked don't know why but i am happy.